# Getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', " <!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" after moving URL value to web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Previously, our url was harcoded in the repository for this feature like so:
`private const string APIUrl = "api/news/newsfilter";`
I've moved it to the web.config file within this same folder like this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="NewsFilterApiUrl" value="api/news/newsfilter"/>
  </appSettings>
```

And reference it now like so:

```
private static string APIUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsFilterApiUrl"];
```

However, now I'm getting the aforementioned error in the title when I try to filter news out. I'm pretty new to asp.net applications / architecture - am I missing a step in here?

Comment: And what value are you getting in `APIUrl` now?

Comment: @DavidG important piece I left there. I'm getting a null value. There are tons of web.config files in our project and I've put this in several places, but it's not seeming to pick up still.

Comment: Then add that to the question! We are not psychic. How can other config values be working though? Ths XML snippet above only shows one.

Comment: ahh, I'll have to close this. I figured it out, but it supposed to go into a setting file that deals with sitecore (which is our cms). I don't fully know the details but nonetheless this can be closed. Thanks though!